# Keep getting IDLE internal exception TypeError, but its not telling me where the problem is

Tags: python, typeerror, python-idle

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
** IDLE Internal Exception: 
TypeError: The fill character must be exactly one character long
```

I'm using Python 3.9.1 IDLE, and my code is too long to paste here, but any ideas to what this is referring to? Please help me out.

Comment: what is the size of your code?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that exact error message only comes from the string methods `.ljust()`, `.rjust()`, and `.center()`.  Does that help you in producing a small example that exhibits the same problem?

Comment: I've figured out the problem, it had to do with .center() and these few comments helped me out like crazy thank you.

Comment: Shafei, I think `Internal Exception` may be an error or partly so.  AFAIK, IDLE never calls .center or .r/ljust.  Can you tell me, or add to your question, the minimal code that causes this?  So I can investigate the IDLE code?  WAs that really all of the traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python throws TypeError: The fill character must be exactly one character long, when a function is expecting a single character and if we pass more than one character. Below is the example

```
str5 = 'SomeRandomText'.rjust(20,'*&')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-2-aa79aef1750e>", line 1, in <module>
str5 = 'SomeRandomText'.rjust(20,'*&')
TypeError: The fill character must be exactly one character long`enter code here`
```

The above example is about using Python rjust method, it is used to Justify the string to the Right-hand side and fill the remaining width with the specified character

Syntax:-

```
String_Value.rjust(Width, Char)
```

If the Char length is more than 1, error "**the fill character must be exactly one character long**" is raised.